# How does the tilted facets "introduce a phase term" to function in blazed grating?

Tags: optics, spectroscopy

I am trying to understand a sentence on section "The blazed reflection grating" of [The Observation and Analysis of Stellar Photospheres](https://books.google.co.jp/books/about/The_Observation_and_Analysis_of_Stellar.html?id=LfNCXBqZab0C&source=kp_cover&redir_esc=y).

After saying a large part of light is lost to zero order of maximum, and we want to use higher order, it states that

> To solve this problem, the diffraction envelope must be shifted relative to the interference pattern to those $\theta$ value where we wish to work. The Fourier shift theorem tells us that we can accomplish this by introducing a phase term in $B_1(x)$. When this is done the grating is said to be blazed.

[image]

In previous section it is proven that the resultant waves behind the grating can be written as the Fourier transform of grating transmission $G(x)$. The function of facets is to change the direction of light, then shine it into the place of higher order.

But what I don't understand here is that how the facets "introducing a phase term in $B_1(x)$"?

Answer (score 1):

For normal gratings, $B_1(x)$ is real and binary, "1" for transmission and "0" for non-transmission. But a blazed grating will introduce a tilted surface of each rectangular function, as a result, introducing a phase term of something like "$exp(-ikx)$", now $B_1(x)$ will become complex.